# GitLab - Secure Connection Failed error on firefox

Tags: firefox, gitlab, mozilla, gitlab-ce

Recently i have re-installed my GitLab application on my Linux system. When i tried to access my GitLab application link (https://gitlab.domain.com) on Windows system's Firefox browser i am getting below error.

[image: Firefox error]

Since the certificate generated freshly it was conflicting with existing/previous certificate, So i have followed this [Link](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Certificate-contains-the-same-serial-number-as-another-certificate) workaround. However even after system reboot also same error occurring, I can't access my GitLab application on Firefox browser.

I'm able to access it on Chrome browser without any problem.

Please let me know still where i need to clear the old certificate to make it work on firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems to be the same error as in [issue 435013](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=435013) reported 13 years ago (and still open), where Firefox has an issue with routers and [NSS (Network Security Services)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Security_Services) ([error -8054](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/SSL_functions/sslerr))

> As I understand it, and from the [discussion on #312732](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=312732) which is the underlying issue, the problem is that the crypto uses the cert ID as a unique key in a database.
>
> When a dupe is encountered, you can't have two primary keys in a database, so it just dies with a fatal error, hence FireFox gives up connecting to the site and passes on the fatal error to be presented.

> This is not a "fundamental NSS design issue", it's a political issue, Firefox is ACTIVELY refusing to let people access their network equipment.

Check also the firmware of your router:

> It seems to me that it is VERY EASY for the server-side products that
> generate these certificates to more-or-less fix the problem in updated
> firmware with very little effort. Even simply randomizing the serial numbers
> in the certs, they would nearly completely eliminate the problem, AFAICT. In
> fact, it is worth making sure that the affected server-side hardware has
> up-to-date firmware, because some vendors might have already fixed it on
> their end already.

Possible workaround (which would work even after FF restart)

> This is hardly any fix, but I installed a new Mozilla from scratch on a VM under Virtualbox.
> I than browsed to all my local systems I was getting this error.  On connecting from the new Window3s sytem running on VM to each local IP, I received the warning, and created the exception.
>
> I than went in to `Preferences>Advanced`, and Exported all the certificates to a share on one of my NAS units.
>
> I proceeded back to the broken Mozilla running on my Mac OS X 10.11.1, and I Imported all the certificates.
> I then restarted FF, and connected to each device I was getting the error on, and I received the "`This is an untrusted connection, Get me out of here, or would you like to create an exception.`" YES!!
> I created the exception, and finally I could get to my firewalls, and all other local devices.

Other workaround:

> 1. Run: `firefox --no-remote --ProfileManager`
> 2. Create a new profile there.
> 3. Open a new instance of Firefox using the new profile. To run Firefox with the profile you can use the command from 1. or: `firefox --no-remote -P profile_name`
> 4. Do the actions there as if it was a separate installation of Firefox

Comment: Thanks a lot with the last `Other workaround` i have created new profile and now it is working fine.